# MVC - correct use of Response.Statuscode assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a question regarding the use of setting `Response.StatusCode` in my MVC site. Specifically, do we need to set this and if so when?

In my Error controller's action I set the status code. Locally my browser shows the page just fine but when deployed to test and staging servers the browser shows its stock 404 or 500 error page and my error page does not show.

I have deduced that it is because of the assignment to `Response.StatusCode`.

```
public ActionResult ShowError(int id)
{
    Response.StatusCode = id;

    if (id == 404)
    {
        // set viewbag with text for 404
    }
    else // 500
    {
        // set viewbag with text for 500
    }
    return View();
}
```

When an unhandled exception occurs, or an unknown page is requested, my Error controller kicks in and works fine - at least locally, or on the server if I remove the `Response.StatusCode` line.

In MVC, do I need to set the `Response.StatusCode` ever?

Comment: Disable "User friendly error pages" in the "browser" IE.

Comment: include `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;` and see if that helps.